# O atributo tabindex funciona no navegador opera?

Tags: html

No caniuse.com (http://caniuse.com/#feat=tabindex-attr) o suporte está como desconhecido.

Imagino que como é a mesma base do chrome, deve funcionar, porém é um tiro no escuro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[No próprio link que postou](http://caniuse.com/#feat=tabindex-attr) fala que suporta.

veja a imagem abaixo que foi retirada do link :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja também o que diz a [Mozilla Developer Network (MDN) documentation - tabindex attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex#Compatibilidade_nos_Navegadores) diz:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você também pode olhar no [html.spec.whatwg.org](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#attr-tabindex), que por sinal, utiliza o [caniuse.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=tabindex-attr)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]